# VS Code не видит интерпретатор Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Несколько недель борюсь с проблемой, Visual Studio Code не видит интерпретатор Python. Пробовал на версиях 3.10.1 и 3.8.3. Но думаю, дело не в python вообще, т.к VS 2019, Atom работают исправно. Но после запуска VS Code, расширение Python выдаёт ошибку, и говорит что Python не установлен, и нужно его установить. Я пытался вручную указывать пути к интерпретатору, но это не помогает. В Выходных данных/output VS Code пишет: `No python is installed or a refresh has not already been triggered.`. Проблема решается переустановкой VS Code, но к сожалению, через 2-3 запуска программы, начинается тоже самое. До этого работал в VS Code несколько месяцев, всё было хорошо, но ни с того, ни с чего началась эта проблема. Просто на ровном месте, ничего не обновляя.

Comment: операционная система какая?

Comment: Windows 10 операционная система

Comment: anaconda пользуете?

Comment: Анакондой не пользуюсь

Comment: хм, расширение для python конечно же стоит. А можете показать список интерпетаторов ? Для этого нажмите F1, а затем в строку вбейте вот это `Python: Select Interprete`

Comment: Стоит, оно мне и высвечивает ошибку о отсутствии Python, вместе с VS Code пишут это. Я бы показал вам список интерпретаторов, но показывать нечего их там попросту нет, хотя в самом поле ввода написано: `Current: и путь к существующему интерпретатору`. Вот и вся странность ситуации, он как бы пишет что есть, но в то же время говорит что нет.

Comment: Внес правку в свой последний ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135046/discussion-between-dmitry-and-cyp4ik31).

Comment: А можно всё же решение вопроса, потому что у меня такая же проблема. Пожалуйста

Comment: вот похоже тот случай, когда люди ушли в чат (а что они там решили - мы не знаем) и чуть ниже человек ответом добавил свой вопрос. Ещё и три комментатора набежало, объяснить ему, что он не прав. Не ходите люди в чат, не вредите.

Comment: Можно и в чат, но для выяснения причин, а вот ответ публиковать не забывать после :)

Comment: Эта ошибка решилась также, как и появилась - сама по себе. Незнаю в чем было дело, но буквально дня 2 назад, все встало на свои места. Но возможно, помогло то, что после переустановки vs code, я отключил автообновления в программе. Сейчас на версии 1.63.0 все нормально работает, и нет проблем. Ох уж эти автообновы, любят что-то обновлять на не стабильную версию, а ты потом сиди гадай что не так, ты же даже ничего не обновлял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта ошибка решилась также, как и появилась - сама по себе. Незнаю в чем было дело, но буквально дня 2 назад, все встало на свои места. Но возможно, помогло то, что после переустановки vs code, я отключил автообновления в программе. Сейчас на версии 1.63.0 все нормально работает, и нет проблем.
P.S. Ох уж эти автообновы, любят что-то обновлять на не стабильную версию, а ты потом сиди гадай что не так, ты же даже ничего не обновлял.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте заново создать окружение, а потом скопировать из него файл pyvenv.cfg и папку Scripts в старое окружение, которое хотите использовать, где уже библиотеки установлены.
Решил проблему:
[Не работает виртуальное окружение в VS Code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560283/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-vs-code/1560284#1560284)