# Не работает виртуальное окружение в VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, powershell, venv

После перехода на другой ПК не работает виртуальное окружение в VS Code, ошибка:
Выбран недопустимый интерпретатор Python. Попробуйте изменить его, чтобы включить такие функции, как IntelliSense, подкладка и отладка. Дополнительные сведения о том, почему интерпретатор недействителен, см. в выходных данных.

Сами данные:

````
2024-01-05 15:11:38.555 [info] Эксперимент «pythonaa» активен
2024-01-05 15:11:38.555 [info] Эксперимент «pythonRecommendTensorboardExt» активен
2024-01-05 15:11:38.555 [info] Эксперимент «pythonREPLSmartSend» активен
2024-01-05 15:11:38.555 [info] Эксперимент «pythonSurveyNotificationcf» активен
2024-01-05 15:11:38.555 [info] Эксперимент «pythonTestAdapter» активен
2024-01-05 15:11:38.592 [info] Default formatter is set to null for workspace d:\Python_my_progs\simple_code
2024-01-05 15:11:38.626 [info] Test server listening.
2024-01-05 15:11:38.653 [info] > conda info --json
2024-01-05 15:11:39.419 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_GLOBAL_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_GLOBAL_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_GLOBAL_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_GLOBAL_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_WORKSPACE_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_WORKSPACE_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_WORKSPACE_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.420 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_WORKSPACE_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.451 [info] > C:\Python310\python.exe -I ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
2024-01-05 15:11:39.843 [warning] Retry failed, storage update failed for key PYTHON_GLOBAL_STORAGE_KEYS
2024-01-05 15:11:39.857 [info] Путь к интерпретатору Python: C:\Python310\python.exe
2024-01-05 15:11:41.539 [info] Запуск языкового сервера Pylance.
2024-01-05 15:12:06.231 [info] > d:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv\Scripts\python.exe -I ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
2024-01-05 15:12:06.293 [error] Error: Command failed: d:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv\Scripts\python.exe -I c:\Users\Yuriy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\Yuriy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
No Python at '"C:\Users\User\Python310\python.exe'
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:431:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: 103,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'd:\\my_venvs\\all_libs_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe -I c:\\Users\\Yuriy\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\\pythonFiles\\get_output_via_markers.py c:\\Users\\Yuriy\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\\pythonFiles\\interpreterInfo.py'
}
2024-01-05 15:12:08.310 [info] > d:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv\Scripts\python.exe -I ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
2024-01-05 15:12:08.354 [error] Error: Command failed: d:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv\Scripts\python.exe -I c:\Users\Yuriy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\Yuriy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
No Python at '"C:\Users\User\Python310\python.exe'
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:431:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: 103,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'd:\\my_venvs\\all_libs_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe -I c:\\Users\\Yuriy\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\\pythonFiles\\get_output_via_markers.py c:\\Users\\Yuriy\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\\pythonFiles\\interpreterInfo.py'
}
2024-01-05 15:12:08.362 [info] > d:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"```
````

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался в чем дело, в выходных данных были ссылки на расширения isort и Flake8, удалил их в VS Code, причем Flake8 надо искать по поиску, т.к. оно неактивно. Потом удалил в VS Code расширение Python, закрыл VS Code и заново создал виртуальное окружение - в папке выше командой python -m venv all_libs_venv
all_libs_venv это имя папки с моим окружением.
Потом открыл VS Code, заново установил расширение Python, указал путь к виртуальному окружению, ошибка ушла, но появилась новая даже не ошибка, а предупреждение:
`D:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv_backup\Scripts\Activate.ps1 : Невозможно загрузить файл D:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv_backup\Scripts\Activate.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execution_Policies по адресу https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. строка:1 знак:1 D:\my_venvs\all_libs_venv_backup\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

Тут проблема в том, что в Windows по умолчанию отключено в целях безопасности выполнение сценариев, поэтому надо включить:
закрываем VS Code и далее:

1. Откройте PowerShell с правами администратора:
   • Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на ярлык PowerShell.
   • Выберите "Запуск от имени администратора".
2. Проверьте текущую политику выполнения: Выполните команду:

Get-ExecutionPolicy
3. Измените политику выполнения: Если политика выполнения установлена в Restricted (что означает отключено), измените ее на RemoteSigned или Unrestricted:

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Отвечаем Y
После этого все должно работать, можем проверить снова командой Get-ExecutionPolicy, будет написано:
RemoteSigned
Теперь можно открывать VS Code и спокойно работать.